# GemFire9.0.3 creation of Region

Tags: distributed-system, gemfire

Need Help: In GemFire9.0.3 is there a Rest API to create a region?

PS: The swagger view shows all the rest API's except the creation of Region.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not an admin REST API which lets you create regions.